# Is it possible to save multiple items in an array to a mysql database?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I was wondering if I can save all positions in an array with one line of code rather than saving each position in an array to a variable and writing an sql update query manually for each individual variable?

I hope that makes sense, I have 40 items which I am pulling from an array in **json** format and writing them all in a query will be a huge block of code.

Comment: You may want to use `serialize` http://php.net/serialize

Comment: Thanks i'll look into it